# Large sparse matrix to matrix error

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, large-data, r-mice

I want to apply *mice* package, but I cannot convert large sparse matrix to matrix.

```
library(Matrix)
library(mice)

i=c(2,9,6:10^7)
j=c(2,9,6:10^7)
x=7*(1:7^7)

write.csv(a,"a.csv")
c=read.csv("a.csv")
w=sparseMatrix(i=c[,1],j=c[,2],x=c[,3])

w=as.matrix(w)
```

> ```
> Error in asMethod(object) : 
>       Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
> ```

Comment: `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'a' not found` (line 6)

Comment: What is `a` and why write and read it? I'm skeptical that you can hold a 1e7 x 1e7 dense matrix in RAM and work with it.

Comment: I have huge data and it looks like:[link](https://www.quora.com/Loading-a-sparse-matrix-in-r-from-list).
I need to apply sparseMatrix to recover it.

Comment: do you have at least 800gb of ram? (1e7*1e7 * (8<byte per double>) = 800gb )